# Consulta SQL dentro do java

Tags: java, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta dentro de um arquivo `jsp` no Java.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName = ? ";
```

Eu gostaria que a minha consulta ignorasse *camel case* e retornasse todas as palavras que tivessem parte da `string`. Por exemplo, **Mesa** retornasse **mesa** para *camel case* e **phone** retornasse **iphone**, **cellphone**, etc..

Como posso fazer isso?

Já tentei usar `%`, `LIKE` e não funciona.

Comment: "Mesa retornasse mesa para camel case" ?!!

Comment: Acho que você quer fazer `SELECT * FROM products WHERE LOWER(productName) LIKE '%' + nome + '%';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso terá de usar, efetivamente, o `LIKE` com o *wildcard* `%`.

Se estiver utilizando um `PreparedStatement`, que é o que parece, terá de colocar o *wildcard* no valor que pretende pesquisar, assim:

```
// vamos supor que existe uma variável 'productName' 
// onde teremos o valor a pesquisar
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
    con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM products WHERE productName LIKE ?");
pstmt.setString(1, "%" + productName + "%");
```

Isto fará uma pesquisa pelo valor `phone` no início, meio e fim em todos os valores da coluna `productName`.

Comment: muito obrigado! funcionou!